# Как определить отношения между таблицами в DataSet?

Tags: c#, xml

С помощью `DataSet.Readxmlschema` загрузил xsd схему, на основании которой был создан набор таблиц `DataTable`. Возможно ли узнать отношения\связи между этими таблицами?
update: а как узнать самую главную таблицу и построить всю цепочку до конца?

update: вот так получаю массив самых конечных таблиц

```
List<DataTable> child_table = new List<DataTable>();
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
   if (table.ChildRelations.Count == 0)
        {
            child_table.Add(table);
        }
}
```

но теперь проблема как получить их родителей, в свойствах связи члены закрыты.

Comment: `DataTable.ChildRelations`, `DataTable.ParentRelations`?

Comment: а как узнать самую главную таблицу и построить всю цепочку до конца?

Comment: Что за "главная" таблица? И где "конец"? Если у вас есть таблицы Проект, Сотрудник и СотрудникПроект, какая из них главнее и какая находится в конце?

Comment: Если судить по xsd схеме то главная скорее всего будет та, которая включает в себя следующую.

Comment: Т.е. если перевернуть это определение, главная -- та таблица, которая не является чайлдом ни в одном из отношений. Так составьте список всех таблиц, затем пробегите по `DataSet.Relations` и составьте список child таблиц (`DataRelation.ChildTable`), и наконец посмотрите, какая (или какие) таблицы являются корневыми. А дальше уже и про цепочку поймете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте свойство [Relations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.dataset.relations(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: а как узнать самую главную таблицу и построить всю цепочку до конца?